# Angularjs with Web API Windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I have the following architecture:

1- Angularjs website hosted on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6 (Server 1).

2- Web API hosted on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7 (Server 2).

3- Database containing the users with their roles and privileges. The username of the user is the same as his windows user.

I want to authenticate the users connecting to the web api through the website without the need to display login screen based on their login windows account.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this requirement? if Yes, can you please share?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this requirement yet. The problem is how to get the user requesting the angular website not the API, because the API will always be called by the angular website user in IIS.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But an alternative approach would be (like the way that I'm planning to do) is to make a http request from the Angular App to the API and get the windows logon user, authenticate and return back to the Angular app.